# Converting Turf Polygon to Leaflet Polygon

Tags: leaflet, turf, typescript, leaflet-geoman

I'm using Geoman and Turf to handle polygons on my map. In order to add a new functionality, I have to transfer an element from a function where it's typed as a Turf Polygon to another function which needs a Leaflet Polygon. Of course, both types are different and I need a way to transform my element.

An example of existing code, as required by the rules of this website:

```
var polygon = turf.polygon([[[125, -15], [113, -22], [154, -27], [144, -15], [125, -15]]]);
```

Is there any built in function in either package to do this (I doubt it)? Or any handmade solution to do it?

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: Hello @TomazicM . I didn't put any existing code since nothing seemed really relevant to me. Should I put the two types (they can be found easily) ? Should I put both my functions (what they do and how they do it would make my post more complex while not giving relevant information in my mind) ?

Comment: Add whatever code you deem relevant to the problem so that person posting the solution won't have to type the code and there won't be comments need from you "Yes, but I don't have it like this, I have it like that'. As I wrote, if you don't post relevant code of what you have, question will most likely be closed.

Comment: Sorry for the awful welcome, there are some very pedantic people ruling on this site who do not consider the humans behind the questions. It is absolutely ridiculous to force you do add "code" to this very specific and clear question about specific types of two libraries. I added code that fulfills the requirements for you.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Just a question: so you think it's quite natural that person asking the question can expect well explained answer with paragraph or two of explanation and ten lines of code, but it's awfully impolite and rude for person answering the question to expect from person asking the question simple copy/paste of some code?

Comment: I consider it very rude and impolite for new users to be greeted by misapplied, draconian rules and their questions being closed for no good reason. This question is not about code specific to the user. It is about two types of two libraries and transforming between the two. The two types are mentioned clearly as is the problem of the user. The only relevant code bit would be a variable name. What exactly did you want as code?

Comment: Thank you bugmenot123 for your support. Are the rules satisfied by the modification @TomazicM ?

Comment: Yes, if you are satisfied with bugmenot123 edit. By the way, what is your opinion on the discussion above? Would it really be so hard to copy/paste a few lines of your own code? From my experience I know that sometimes code can tell more than thousand words.

Comment: While I understand the rule asking for a bit of code to help people answer the question (and support you when you're saying it's hard to do), in this specific case, I don't find it relevant. I don't want an answer related to my code, my question is "how to convert this type A into this type B" (both being libraries built in types) and I still think that it's better if not crowded with specific examples. But no problem if you disagree !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `geometryToLayer` method of `L.GeoJSON` (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-geometrytolayer) to get Leaflet polygon from GeoJSON polygon:

```
var polygon = turf.polygon([[[125, -15], [113, -22], [154, -27], [144, -15], [125, -15]]]);
var polygonLayer = L.GeoJSON.geometryToLayer(polygon);
```

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/o9daL842/

Comment: Unfortunately, this function does not accept the correct type :
` Argument of type 'Polygon' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Feature<Geometry, any>'.
  Type 'Polygon' is missing the following properties from type 'Feature<Geometry, any>': geometry, properties`

Comment: See working JSFiddle in modified answer.

Comment: thank you ! it works

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to add to @TomazicM answer:

```
var leafletPolyCords= L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(polygon.geometry.coordinates[0]);

                    L.polygon( leafletPolyCords, {
                        color: 'blue',
                        fillColor: 'blue',
                        fillOpacity: 0.5,
                        radius: 0.5
                    }).addTo(map);
```